# why does calling `length` on an ActiveRecord relation change the size?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, relationship

On Rails 4.2.10 I have this model:

```
class RegistrationApproval < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :registering_user, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :registration_approvals
  belongs_to :approver, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :approved_registrations
end
```

And in my `User` model I have this:

```
has_many :registration_approvals, foreign_key: 'registering_user_id', dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :registering_user
has_many :registration_approvers, through: :registration_approvals, class_name: 'User', source: :approver, inverse_of: :registering_users
has_many :approved_registrations, class_name: 'RegistrationApproval', foreign_key: 'approver_id', dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :approver
has_many :registering_users, through: :approved_registrations, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :registration_approvers

def approve_registration(approver)
  registration_approvals.create(approver: approver)
  Rails.logger.debug "approvers: #{registration_approvers.length}"
  return [registration_approvers.size, registration_approvers.count]
end
```

In the the `approve_registration` method the debug statement changes the output of that method. Without the debug statement the when there are two approvals for the user `registration_approvers.size` evaluates to `2` as you would expect, but with the debug statement it evaluates to `1`. Why does this happen? Is this a bug in Rails 4.2?

The `count` evaluation remains unaffected.

It seems to be the call to `registration_approvers.length` that causes the change in `size`

Here is a failing test I have that shows this problem:

```
 it 'should have size and count equal' do
    registering_user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
    _(registering_user).must_be :persisted?
    approver1 = FactoryBot.create(:user)
    _(approver1).must_be :persisted?
    approver2 = FactoryBot.create(:user)
    _(approver2).must_be :persisted?
    registering_user.approve_registration(approver1)
    size, count = registering_user.approve_registration(approver2)
    _(count).must_equal 2
    _(size).must_equal 2
  end
```

All the asserts in the test pass except the one in the last line that fails because `size` is `1`. The test passes when the call to `registration_approvers.length` is removed from the `approve_registration` method.

This is a problem for me since in the `approve_registration` method I want to iterate through the `registration_approvers` with `each` but when I do that it misses the last in the collection, presumably because the `each` method calls `length` on the collection and changes the value of size and then quits the loop early thinking it's reached the end.

If I can get a workaround way of iterating through that collection without having `length` called on it, that would help a bit.

Comment: Can you even read those infinitely long has_many definitions? :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I am using some shortcuts and I flagged your comment for mistake

Comment: keep in mind that `registration_approvers` is an `ActiveRecord::Association` object  https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html but I don't think that length is defined in that class, it could be inherited from a parent... I believe the result from the queries are arrays so https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#size` uses the `#length` value when the query results have been loaded, [see the doc's code snippet](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-size).

`#length` doesn't trigger a new query, but simply calls #length on an array of (previously obtained / cached) results.

OTOH: `#count` does trigger a new query (and actually it is triggered the first time when the results haven't been loaded yet.

So to fix the test, you could actively reload the object, and hence flushing the results' cache:

```
registering_user.approve_registration(approver1)
registering_user.reload
size, count = registering_user.approve_registration(approver2)
```

Besides that I'd think it would be better to not rely on a return value of an action for statistics.

Comment: Thanks! BTW, I'm not relying on that return value for statistics - I only added it to illustrate the problem using a test. The problem was causing me not to be able to iterate over the collection within that method because it would exit the loop early.

Answer (score 0):

fkeep in mind that registration_approvers is an [ActiveRecord::Association](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) object but I don't think that length is defined in that class, it could be inherited from a parent...

I believe the result from the queries are arrays so but I don't think that length is defined in that class, it could be inherited from a parent... I believe the result from the queries are [arrays](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-length)

this is the ruby source code for that method

```
static VALUE
rb_ary_length(VALUE ary)
{
    long len = RARRAY_LEN(ary);
    return LONG2NUM(len);
}
```

I would need some points/feedback from you